# Generar 3 números aleatorios infinitamente entre 0 y 1000, cuando se dé esta condición detener el programa. en java

Tags: java

me he atascado en un problema, que consiste en generar 3 números aleatorios de forma infinita hasta que se cumpla una condición,
estos 3 números que se generen, deben de ser de esta forma, el numeroA tiene que ser par, (a%2==0)
y el segundo número que se genere, debe de ser su siguiente par ascendente, y el tercer número, debe de ser el impar que está entre estos dos números.

algo así:
infinitos randoms: 5456 45 645 756 76 876 86 5657 85 8768 98  [24 , 26 , 25]
43535 5345 656 767 878 [234 ,236 ,235]
hasta que ocurra esto.

Hasta ahora se me ha ocurrido lo siguiente.

```
        int numeroA = 0;
        int numeroB = 0;
        int numeroC = 0;
        int contador = 0;
        int finNumA = 0, finNumB = 0, finNumC = 0;
        boolean finales1 = false, finales2 = false, finales3 = false;
        do {
            numeroA = (int) (Math.random() * 1000);
            numeroB = (int) (Math.random() * 1000);
            numeroC = (int) (Math.random() * 1000);

            if (numeroA % 2 == 0) {
                finNumA = numeroA;
                System.out.println(numeroA);
                finales1 = true;
            }
            if (numeroA + 2 == numeroB) {
                finNumB = numeroB;
                System.out.println(numeroB);
                finales2 = true;
            }
            if (finNumA + 1 == numeroC && finNumB - 1 == numeroC) {
                finNumC = numeroC;
                System.out.println(numeroC);
                finales3 = true;
            }
            contador++;

        } while (finales1==true || finales2==true || finales3 == true);
        System.out.println("Los 3 numeros son: a "+ finNumA + " b " +finNumB +" c " + finNumC + " en " + contador + " veces ");
```

pero no veo el fallo.

me debería de salir algo así Los 3 números son: a 234 b 236 c 233 en x veces

Comment: Lo que describes que quieres hacer con el ejemplo que has puesto no cuadra... Quieres que: 1) numero par (X), 2) siguiente numero par (X+2), 3) numero entre ellos (X+1). Y en el ejemplo pones de argumentos válidos [24,26,23] y [234,236,233], cuando debería ser [24,26,25] y [234,236,235]. Entonces... ¿a qué premisa hacemos caso?

Comment: perdón, me confundí puse 23 era un 25 y un 235

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay varias cosas que son de matemática/lógica.

- Si el primero debe ser exclusivamente par, y el segundo exclusivamente el par siguiente, entonces buscas anidar ifs y no hacerlos uno atrás del otro. En este caso, yo evaluaría las tres expresiones como A and B and C.
- Dadas las dos primeras condiciones, con una sola de estas `(finNumA + 1 == numeroC && finNumB - 1 == numeroC)` es suficiente.
- No cambias las 3 variables lógicas dentro del bucle. Al evaluarlas una atrás de la otra vas a ir acumulando valores verdaderos cada vez que aparezcan. En la primer vuelta, la primer condición puede cumplirse. Sin importar que las otras no se cumplan, finales1 queda verdadero de ahí en adelante, y así para las otras 2.
- El bucle que hacés debería iterar infinitamente hasta cumplir la condición, pero escribís `(finales1==true || finales2==true || finales3 == true)`, que es iterar mientras alguna de las tres sea válida. El bucle que cumpla las 3 debería ser `(finales1==true && finales2==true && finales3 == true)`.

No tengo JAVA en esta máquina, pero asumo que esto debería funcionar para lo que querés:

```java
int numeroA = 0;
int numeroB = 0;
int numeroC = 0;
int contador = 0;

do {
   numeroA = (int) (Math.random() * 1000);
   numeroB = (int) (Math.random() * 1000);
   numeroC = (int) (Math.random() * 1000);

   contador++;
} while ((numeroA % 2 != 0) ||
        (numeroB != (numeroA + 2)) ||
        (numeroC != (numeroA + 1)));

System.out.println("Los 3 numeros son: a "+ numeroA + " b " + numeroB +" c " + numeroC + " en " + contador + " veces ");
```

La condición de salida es `((a es par) and (b==a+2) and (c==a+1))`, por lo tanto la condición del while, que es la de continuación, es su forma negada: `~((a es par) and (b==a+2) and (c==a+1))`, o lo que es lo mismo aplicando leyes de Morgan: `(~(a es par) or ~(b==a+2) or ~(c==a+1))`.

Comment: No comprendo para que generar el random de los 3 números si solo con sacar el primer número random se puede sacar los siguientes, de esta manera se derrocha mucho en procesos innecesarios a la hora de la ejecución. Eso es algo que debería tener en cuenta todo desarrollador a la hora de programar. De igual manera entiendo que es por el ejercicio como lo plantean

Comment: Es que se generan 3 números a la vez, una serie de 3  números x veces  , hasta que se de lo que planteo.

Comment: @D4RIO gracias por tu tiempo y tu respuesta.

Comment: @jGomez, hay casos y casos, en este caso la finalidad no es obtener 3 números consecutivos (pseudo)aleatoriamente empezando por un par, sino evaluar cuántas veces se tienen que generar 3 números aleatorios para que el resultado sean 3 números consecutivos, empezando por un par. El contador te hace a la diferencia. Esta clase de cosas se puede hacer, por ejemplo, para evaluar la generación de números pseudoaleatorios con técnicas estadísticas.